# Dynamically creating new variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of creating a site that allows users to post messages.  When a user clicks on a name in their contact list, that contact becomes a variable and is added as a recipient to the message.

```
echo "<td><a href='mypagepost.php?contact=$contact' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><font color=#808080>" . $row['contact'] . "</a></font></td>";
```

This is the link created in the user's recipient list.  So, it takes them to mypagepost.php.  At mypagepost.php, I have;

```
<?php $messagerecipient = $_GET['contact']; ?>
```

And this works.  Depending on the contact clicked on the contacts list on mypage.php, it will be stored as $messagerecipient.  However, I would like to set it up so that if I continue to click on more recipients from mypagepost.php, new variables will be created that can also be used in the same way (so, maybe the new variables would become $messagerecipient2, $messagerecipient3, and so forth).  Is there a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated, as always.

Comment: Why are you just storing them in a database? Since you already tagged it with mysql. Or you can store them in a SESSION.

Comment: Please learn about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: While neither me nor you have any influence over winning the lottery, we do have a choice of choosing what to learn. Your question is typical to people, who never heard about arrays, or for some reason do not understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an array in HTML?

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="text" name="recipient[]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Example URL:

```
recipient%5B%5D=k&recipient%5B%5D=g&recipient%5B%5D=b&recipient%5B%5D=n&recipient%5B%5D=m&recipient%5B%5D=%2C
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [0] => k
            [1] => g
            [2] => b
            [3] => n
            [4] => m
            [5] => l
        )

)
```